# Getting duplicate target while monitoring external service with in kubernetes deployed Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, servicemonitor

I'm trying to monitor a server external to kubernetes, which works. The problem is i'm getting a duplicate target and a second scrapejob. It's the same target with slightly different scrape intervals and metric paths. I don't know where it's coming from, as it doesn't do that on a similar deployment, which is basically a copy of this one with different labels, which also monitors an external service.

Anyone ever encountered the same problem?
here are the Monitor and Config

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: generic-lable-at-dev-stage
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    app: generic-lable-at
    prometheus: generic-lable-at
spec:
  jobLabel: generic-lable-at-dev-stage
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: generic-lable-at-dev-stage
    namespaceSelector:
      matchNames:
      - monitoring
  endpoints:
  - interval: 15s
  - basicAuth:
      password:
        name: prometheus-generic-lable-at-basic-auth
        key: password
      username:
        name: prometheus-generic-lable-at-basic-auth
        key: user
    path: /metrics
    port: http-monitoring
    honorLabels: true
---
job_name: serviceMonitor/monitoring/generic-lable-at-dev-stage/0
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 15s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
  follow_redirects: true
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [job]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: __tmp_prometheus_job_name
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_app, __meta_kubernetes_service_labelpresent_app]
    separator: ;
    regex: (generic-lable-at-dev-stage);true
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: Node;(.*)
    target_label: node
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: Pod;(.*)
    target_label: pod
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: namespace
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: service
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: pod
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: container
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: job
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_shop_generic_at_dev_stage]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.+)
    target_label: job
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    modulus: 1
    target_label: __tmp_hash
    replacement: $1
    action: hashmod
  - source_labels: [__tmp_hash]
    separator: ;
    regex: "0"
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: endpoints
    kubeconfig_file: ""
    follow_redirects: true
    namespaces:
      own_namespace: false
      names:
      - monitoring
- job_name: serviceMonitor/monitoring/generic-lable-at-dev-stage/1
  honor_labels: true
  honor_timestamps: true
  scrape_interval: 30s
  scrape_timeout: 10s
  metrics_path: /metrics
  scheme: http
  basic_auth:
    username: generic
    password: <secret>
  follow_redirects: true
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [job]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: __tmp_prometheus_job_name
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_app, __meta_kubernetes_service_labelpresent_app]
    separator: ;
    regex: (generic-lable-at-dev-stage);true
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: http-monitoring
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: Node;(.*)
    target_label: node
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: Pod;(.*)
    target_label: pod
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: namespace
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: service
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: pod
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: container
    replacement: $1
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: job
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_label_shop_generic_at_dev_stage]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.+)
    target_label: job
    replacement: ${1}
    action: replace
  - separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    target_label: endpoint
    replacement: http-monitoring
    action: replace
  - source_labels: [__address__]
    separator: ;
    regex: (.*)
    modulus: 1
    target_label: __tmp_hash
    replacement: $1
    action: hashmod
  - source_labels: [__tmp_hash]
    separator: ;
    regex: "0"
    replacement: $1
    action: keep
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: endpoints
    kubeconfig_file: ""
    follow_redirects: true
    namespaces:
      own_namespace: false
      names:
      - monitoring
```